# issue dealing the ResultSet Value in Eclipse Rcp

Tags: java, eclipse, resultset

My ResultSet Query is

```
StrQry = "select SUM(isnull(prn_amount,0))as prn_amount,SUM(isnull(adv_prn,0))as adv_prn, SUM(isnull(prv_prn,0))as prv_prn from loan_transaction_mcg where loan_id='1117'";
```

It is giving the result as on Sql

1. prn_amount =NULL
2. adv_prn    =NULL
3. prv_prn    =NULL

*when the loan id =1117*

```
ResultSet RsPrincipalDetail = getPaidDetail(loan_id);

        while(RsPrincipalDetail.next()){

        prn1 = RsPrincipalDetail.getString("prn_amount");
        prn2 = RsPrincipalDetail.getString("adv_prn");
        prn3 = RsPrincipalDetail.getString("prv_prn");
        if(prn1.equals("")){
            prn1.equals("0");               
        }
        if(prn2.equalsIgnoreCase("")){
            prn2.equals("0");               
        }
        if(prn3.equalsIgnoreCase("")){
            prn3.equals("0");               
        }
```

I tried putting  prn1.equals(null) but still the **null pointer exception** comes. I tried in debug mode on ***prn1***, it is showing as ***null*** as its value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that since your values in database are NULL when you convert them to java values using getString they will also be null.

Since null is not the same as empty string you can not really use prn.equals("")

Also using prn.equals(null) is a bad idea as usually the way that equals is implemented ... it will return false if something that it is compared to is null

Your best bet is to use equality operator to check for null

if(prn == null)

Answer (score 0):

What are the column names of the table?

For me this seems to be possibly cyclic:

```
SUM(isnull(prn_amount,0))as prn_amount
```

and there seems to be a `group by` missing in your statement on loan_id